# https://localhost:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel takes 16 seconds

Tags: windows-10, printing

When using the Dymo Labelwriter javascript to print via the service on 
`https://localhost:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/PrintLabel`, the debugger shows it takes around 16 seconds for the call to print the label and return "true".
The same for the `RenderLabel` call.

This happens on both Chrome and edge, current versions on windows 10.

I've reinstalled the labelwriter software to the latest version.

The strange thing is that this happens on two machines, but on a third the printing is done in about 500ms. All (afaik) are up to date on updates.

Comment: Perhaps the printer drivers haven't been installed correctly?  Did you reboot the problematic systems?

Comment: The printer prints immediately from the Dyno label program, so the printer is fine, it is the print server on 41951 being slow.

Comment: Is the "Dyno label program" running on the same systems?  Anything in the event logs about the print server?

Comment: The "Dymo lapel program" is the one which can be downloiaded from the dymo site, and yes, it is running on the same machine which is slow on printing labels from the web via the dymo service on port 41951

Comment: other calls to the dymo printservice like https://localhost:41951/DYMO/DLS/Printing/GetPrinters works in 10ms.

Comment: Well, GetPrinters isn't really printing, is it?   Event logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76436/discussion-between-lenne-and-gerard-h-pille).

Comment: Appearently some other user also have this problem on 16 machines, but chose to delete his comments.Strange.

Comment: There is another thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987169/dymo-label-web-service-printing-slow. I'll continue there.

Comment: Do that, in the mean time I'll check your event logs, eh?

Answer (score 0):

This was severely limiting a client's ability to do business so I broke out Procmon and got to the bottom of this.

It appears to be due to the Dymo Label Service querying 128.30.52.100 (hans-moleman.w3.org) every time it was fed a label to validate its schema. We were not being rate limited by this service until today.

Setting an outbound firewall rule against this IP address for the DLS service executable fixed the issue.

Comment: CAN YOU CLARIFY THE ANSWER? What did you do in the firewall? Block the address? redirect it? I am having the same issue here. Thought it had something to do with TLS

Comment: Try the following powershell command
`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "dymo-xsd-exclude" -Direction Outbound -Action Block -Program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dymo\DYMO Label Software\DYMO.DLS.Printing.Host.exe" -RemoteAddress 128.30.52.100`

If that doesn't work create a global outbound rule for the same IP. [Here's a generic guide.](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/manage-rules-windows-firewall-advanced-security)

Comment: Dymo is aware of the issue:
http://developers.dymo.com/2018/04/24/recent-issues-with-slow-printing/